# Re-coding Toupper Function

Tags: c

I'm assigned to re-code toUpper and toLower functions. Do I have to write all of 26 alphabets in if statement like:

```
if ( char == 'a' )
return 'A';
```

or there is another simple way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lower-case ASCII characters are sequential](http://www.asciitable.com/), so it's a simple case of offsetting the character's value if it is within a given range:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int to_upper(int value) { return (value >= 'a' && value <= 'z') ? value - ('a'-'A') : value; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%c and %c\n", to_upper('B'), to_upper('f'));
    return 0;
}
```

Try this code online [here](http://codepad.org/WoyIK2IX).

Comment: This works for ASCII only, but since the OP did not mention anything else (not even a programming language!) it might just work.

Comment: @PaulR: how? The code assumes the encoding of `a..z` is *larger* than `A..Z` by a factor `'a'-'A'`, which is not the case for EBCDIC.

Comment: @Jongware: it doesn't have to be *larger* (`'a'-'A'` can be positive or negative). The displacement between a corresponding upper case letter and a lower case letter in EBCDIC is a constant, just like in ASCII.